# Integral with respect to random measure is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, random-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $P$ be a random, $\mathcal{G}$-measurable finite measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, with $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.

Is the following proposition true? Is my proof correct?

*Proposition*. The function $f(\omega) = \int g dP(\omega)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable for all bounded, $\mathcal{F}$-measurable functions $g$.

*Proof*. The proposition holds if $g$ is the indicator function of $A \in \mathcal{F}$ simply because $P(A)(\omega)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable in $\omega$ by definition. Since the bounded $\mathcal{G}$-measurable functions are closed under linear combinations and uniform limits, the entire proposition follows.

Is that sufficient? I'm somehow not fully confident about the last sentence of the proof. Should I add that the bounded convergence theorem is used for the limit step?

Answer (score 2):

No, your argument is not complete. Given $g$ there exist simple functions $g_n,n=1,2,...$ such that $g_n \to g$ uniformly. $\int g_ndP(\omega)$ is measurable for each $n$. To show that $\int gdP(\omega)=\lim \int g_ndP(\omega)$ you will have to assume that the finite measures $dP(\omega)$ have a uniform bound, i.e. $sup_{\omega}P(\omega,\Omega))<\infty$. I hope this is what you meant when you said the random measure $P$ was finite.

Comment: I’m happy to assume P is a random probability. So with that assumption, everything else is okay?

Comment: Actually, why do we need uniform boundedness? Couldn't we treat $\int gdP(\omega)$ as a random variable taking values in $[-\infty, \infty]$?

Comment: Uniform convergence implies convergence of integrals only for finite measures. For example $\int \frac 1 n I_{(n,\infty)}(x)dx$ does not to 0 even though the integrand tends to 0 uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: And $P(\omega)$ is finite for all $\omega$, so what’s the problem?

Comment: It is not enough to assume that $P(\omega)$ is finite for each $\omega$. You need a uniform bound. But you have stated that you are happy to assume that they are probability measures ; in that case there is no problem.